# Error InputStream in Bluetooth on Android

Tags: android

I am writing an application that needs to exchange data with an Arduino HC-06 Bluetooth.  Here is the data exchange method:

```
void ListenForBluetoothData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    if(BTinStream!=null)
                    {
                    int bytesAvailable = BTinStream.available();
                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        BTinStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        myLabel1.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}
```

The main error that I received is:

```
06-19 11:21:23.011 17542-17910/com.example.farok.bluetoothcommunicationarduino E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-41375
Process: com.example.farok.bluetoothcommunicationarduino, PID: 17542
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
    at com.example.farok.bluetoothcommunicationarduino.MainActivity.ListenForBluetoothData(MainActivity.java:179)
    at com.example.farok.bluetoothcommunicationarduino.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:69)
```

Please help, I've tried many solutions and they have not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data to the UI from a worker thread, instead of using `Handler`, edit and use `runOnUiThread`.

Instead of:

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
      myLabel1.setText(data);
   }
});
```

Use this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   public void run() {
      myLabel1.setText(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer..
the error is gone but the app is not respond for received data ..??

Comment: I don't really understand your current problem. What do you mean by "the app is not respond for received data" ?

Comment: I mean that the bluetooth received data from arduino is not showing up in the Label ..

Comment: Try to see if it's null. Make a `Toast` and see the results.